# ionic dynamic views from server

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Framework to develop mobile application. Instead of packing the views with the build, i am wondering is it possible to retrieve the views from the server and push it to $templateCache manually based on the options user choose. This helps me to control and change the views and publish to my server which gets downloaded by the app. This also  helps me to avoid publishing the application to the store again and again when there are some changes in the views.  My big doubt is   whether android/IOS store will reject the build if i publish with this kind of dynamic views.